# Where can I find the cookie_consent_module

Tags: cookies

Where can I find the cookie_consent_module. If I google it and follow the link, it get a 404.

Comment: Maybe you can use this: https://github.com/EllisLab/Cookie

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this link:
https://github.com/yashiel/Cookie-Consent

In `mcp.cookie_consent.php`, line 63 will have to be changed from…

```
$this->EE->cp->set_variable('cp_page_title', $this->EE->lang->line('cookie_consent_module_name'));
```

…to…

```
$this->EE->view->cp_page_title = $this->EE->lang->line('cookie_consent_module_name');
```

As well as in both `upd.cookie_consent.php`, line 67,
and `ext.cookie_consent.php`, line 363, change from…

```
// $this->EE->functions->set_cookie('cookies_allowed', 'y', $expires);
```

…to…

```
$this->input->set_cookie('cookies_allowed', 'y', $expires);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the cookie_consent module from Ellis has been EOL'd with EE2.  If you want to do this a better solution is to use one of the many GDPR compliant solutions around.  Here is a link to a free one that works nicely and might be what you need: https://cookie-bar.eu/

HTH

Comment: Looks like an improved cookie consent module is coming down the pipe from Ellis sometime soon... https://expressionengine.com/blog/gdpr-ellislab-and-expressionengine